# Warping to a warping pilot, where do you end?

Tags: eve-online

If you warp to a ship that's in mid-warp, where do you end up? At the target ship's destination, current or initial position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You end up warping to the pilot's current position. Makes perfect sense: if the pilot would warp 100 AU away, you could start warping before he actually reached the destination.

An exception seem to be deadspaces. You will always warp to the beacon in the first room, i.e. if the pilot would warp in and move 100km away from the beacon, you will still warp to it instead of the pilot.

Answer (score 1):

You warp to the location of the pilot at the moment you requested the warp. If they are in warp, you will land *somewhere* in their warp path.

Comment: This is interesting. Is this going to be resolved with the new updates to have state is managed in the game? Apparently, it would be correct to assume *somewhere* as a good approximation, from what I currently understand. If you would run two clients A, B, on the same machine, and you warp both towards a warping pilot C, the greater the differences between the time the request were resolved with the server between the two clients would mean that they would be farther apart, and this is more pronounced when C is moving at max speed.

Comment: Just to leave a note, the state and changes were historically managed in a way that it required clients to synchronized with the server continuously for updates. When you run two clients and have pilot A and B shoot each other, B might be in such a state that it is damaged, but A is still shooting and not seeing any damage performed because it has not yet received an update from the server. When A would warp, it would still see B flying because it's no longer receiving updates from the solar system it left, but in reality B is warping as well. They are improving how state is observed.

Answer (score -2):

You will land at the point space that they where when you initiated warp.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said, and is therefore subject to deletion.